# Could you recommend me a resource on study of number systems?

Tags: number-systems

I tried to find some recourse on the Internet about number systems. I'd like to know about conversions between different number systems and operations with numbers within them. I tried to find it but there's only tutorials on different methods of how to convert and etc without real explanation of why it is done like that and not some other way but the latter is exactly what I'd like to know. Could you tell me where I can find what I am looking for? May be a book or a website. Sorry if this sounds a little "wavy", I'm novice here. Studying computer science and love math. Just trying to really understand. Thank you really much. 
(about myself, I do not have a big experience with algorithms. I am not some cool "math-guy". I started with math only recently and by the time I do not even know the very basics of calculus.)

Comment: The ideal book for you is the book [**Numbers**](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540556541). It is also available in English [here](https://www.amazon.com/Numbers-Graduate-Mathematics-Heinz-Dieter-Ebbinghaus/dp/0387974970).

Comment: At some point in ones studies it becomes expeditious to tackle problems that motivate learning the theory behind algorithms.  A few words about your past mathematical studies may help Readers to respond more cogently.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the post. So I do not have a big mathematical experience. I am only 1 year into math. But I do understand proofs and I am able to construct some myself (well, that shouldn't suprize anyone, since most of them are in Euclidian geometry..). I do know sentential and predicate logic for example, but I didn't yet came to calculus.

Comment: So how hard would it be to understand about number system for someone who's only recently in math?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: I think, based on "*conversions between different number systems and operations with numbers within them*", the OP is interested in representations and computations and conversions involving binary, ternary, base-10, etc. [positional notation systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) for representing positive integers, so the book you cited is probably several years beyond the OP's current mathematical level.

Comment: Try googling [scales of notation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scales+of+notation%22+%22number%22) (and [scale of notation](https://www.google.com/search?ei=AqePXcadJtvB0PEP8fG56A4&q=%22scale+of+notation%22+%22number%22)) and looking for this topic in [these books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scale+of+notation%22+arithmetic+archive.org).